# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218: laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i want to add new law details with a form, this form has two buttons like update and cancel.

when i hit on cancel button the form gets cancelled and is redirected to previous page, and when i hit update button without filling form details it asks for validation.

after filling all required details of form, when i hit update button it throws me error as MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

my form is this:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/companymaster/updateLocation', 'id'=>'updatelocations', 'class' => 'form-horizontal create_form', 'files' => true)) !!}
<input type="hidden" value="{{$value->id}}" name="company_master_id">
<div id="sublaws_content1"></div>
<div id="save" style="display:none; margin-bottom: 20px;">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="senddatepicker">Update</button>
<a class="btn red" href="{{ URL::to('admin/companymaster/'.$company_master->id) }}">Cancel</a>
</div>
</form>
```

my route is:

```
Route::post('admin/companymaster/updatelocations', 'CompanyController@updateLocation');
```

my controller is:

```
public function updateLocation(){
        //dd(Input::all());
        /*Insert Company Law Details*/
        $companydetails_id = Input::get('company_master_id');
        $company_sub_laws = Input::get('company_sub_laws');
        if($company_sub_laws!="")
        {
            $cld=0;
            foreach($company_sub_laws as $rescompany_sublaws)
            {
                if($companydetails_id!="" && $rescompany_sublaws!="")
                {

                    $law_reg_no = $_POST['law_reg_no'];
                    $sub_law_start_date = $_POST['sub_law_start_date'][$cld];
                    $sub_law_end_date = $_POST['sub_law_end_date'][$cld];

                    $companylawdetails = new CompanyLawDetails;
                    $companylawdetails->company_master_details_id = $companydetails_id;
                    $companylawdetails->company_sub_law_id = $rescompany_sublaws;
                    $companylawdetails->law_reg_no = $law_reg_no;
                    $company_sub_law_start_date = $sub_law_start_date;
                    $company_sub_law_end_date = $sub_law_end_date;

                    if($company_sub_law_end_date!="")
                    {
                        $res_company_sub_law_end_date=explode("-",$company_sub_law_end_date);
                        $company_sub_law_end_date=$res_company_sub_law_end_date[2]."-".$res_company_sub_law_end_date[1]."-".$res_company_sub_law_end_date[0];

                        $companylawdetails->law_end_date = $company_sub_law_end_date;
                    }
                    if($company_sub_law_start_date!="")
                    {
                        $res_company_sub_law_start_date=explode("-",$company_sub_law_start_date);
                        $company_sub_law_start_date=$res_company_sub_law_start_date[2]."-".$res_company_sub_law_start_date[1]."-".$res_company_sub_law_start_date[0];
                        $companylawdetails->law_start_date = $company_sub_law_start_date;
                    }

                    $companylawdetails->save();

                }
                $cld++;
            }
        }

        $sublaws = CompanyLawDetails::where('company_master_details_id',$companydetails_id)->select('company_sub_law_id')->get()->toArray();
        $sublaws = join(",",array_column($sublaws,'company_sub_law_id'));

        $update = CompanyDetails::where('id',$companydetails_id)->update(['company_sub_laws' => $sublaws]);
        //return Redirect::back();
    }
```

when i submit my form by clicking on update button i get an error page as:
[image]

can anyone help me out with this.?

Comment: Just add `'method' => 'post'` to your `Form::open` array!

Comment: Have you tried both spell mistake and add `'method' => 'post'` ?? Do this both and let us know what occurs!

Comment: add method=post and also add {{ csrf_field() }} inside your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are going on the wrong route, and you have an error on url, try this way;

```
Route::post('admin/companymaster/updatelocations', ['uses'=>'CompanyController@updateLocation',
'as'=>'upload.locations']);

on your blade 


{!! Form::open(array('route'=> 'upload.locations', 'method'=>'post', 'id'=>'updatelocations', 'class' => 'form-horizontal create_form', 'files' => true)) !!}
<input type="hidden" value="{{$value->id}}" name="company_master_id">
<div id="sublaws_content1"></div>
<div id="save" style="display:none; margin-bottom: 20px;">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="senddatepicker">Update</button>
<a class="btn red" href="{{ URL::to('admin/companymaster/'.$company_master->id) }}">Cancel</a>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: how to i redirect it to admin/companymaster with its respective id such as admin/companymaster/2 after updating data of form

Comment: forgot that add 'route'=>['upload.locations', $value->id]

Comment: is this wright   Route::post('admin/companymaster/updatelocations', ['uses'=>'CompanyController@updateLocation', 'as'=>'upload.locations', $value->id]);

Comment: u dont need to ad value id to route leave it as I wrote, you get the value as a parameter on updateLocation method on CompanyController

Answer (score 0):

Please add form method as `'method' => 'post',`

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/companymaster/updateLocation', 'id'=>'updatelocations', 'class' => 'form-horizontal create_form', 'files' => true,'method' => 'post')) !!}
```

Hope you understand.

Comment: i have added 'method' => 'post' to my form, but i'm getting same error page

Answer (score 0):

Spelling error change your `url` form

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/companymaster/updateLocation', 'id'=>'updatelocations', 'class' => 'form-horizontal create_form', 'files' => true)) !!}
```

to

```
 {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/companymaster/updatelocations', 'id'=>'updatelocations', 'class' => 'form-horizontal create_form', 'files' => true)) !!}
```

Comment: `url` is case sensitive change `admin/companymaster/updateLocations` to `admin/companymaster/updatelocations`. Just change `L` to `l`

Comment: yes it worked thanks. but i am getting a blank page although data is updated successfully.